# How to setup TestExecutionListener in the application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot project with a large number of test and I want to use extent report. I have created a `TestExecutionListener` and I use the setting in one test.

I don't want to copy the same annotation in all test.

Where do I need to set the `TestExecutionListener`? and how?

Is it possible to set up in the `application.properties`?

Comment: Add a  `spring.factories` to the `META-INF ` to have it automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring-test` module declares all default TestExecutionListeners in its `META-INF/spring.factories` properties file.

Creating a simple Spring application:

MyBean:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
  public void doSomething() {
      System.out.println("-- in MyBean.doSomething() method --");
  }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Writing a TestExecutionListener:

```
public class MyListener implements TestExecutionListener {
  @Override
  public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("MyListener.beforeTestClass()");
  }

  @Override
  public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("MyListener.prepareTestInstance()");

  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("MyListener.beforeTestMethod()");
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("MyListener.afterTestMethod()");
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("MyListener.afterTestClass");
  }
}
```

Writing JUnit test:

A TextExecutionListener can be registered via `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {MyListener.class,
      DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
public class MyTests {

  @Autowired
  private MyBean myBean;

  @Test
  public void testDoSomething() {
      myBean.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Detailed infomation: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/test-execution-listener.html

**EDIT:**

Declaring test property sources

Test properties files can be configured via the locations or value attribute of `@TestPropertySource` as shown in the following example.

Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "`classpath:/com/example/test.properties`" or "`file:///path/to/file.xml`".

Each path will be interpreted as a Spring Resource. A plain path — for example, "test.properties" — will be treated as a classpath resource that is relative to the package in which the test class is defined. A path starting with a slash will be treated as an absolute classpath resource, for example: "/org/example/test.xml". A path which references a URL (e.g., a path prefixed with classpath:, file:, http:, etc.) will be loaded using the specified resource protocol. Resource location wildcards (e.g. */.properties) are not permitted: each location must evaluate to exactly one .properties or .xml resource.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
public class MyTests {
    // class body...
}
```

More info: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source

Comment: The question is about NOT to use the annotation.